# How to group labels in html5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

How can I group labels in a semantic way? e.g.:

If I was making a form about favorite foods, as in:

```html
<form> 
  <label for="food1">Rice</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="food1" name="food"><br>
  <label for="food2">Pasta</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="food2" name="food"><br>
  <label for="food3">Meat</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="food3" name="food"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Would I put a `<h2>Favorite foods</h2>` before them or is there any more semantically appropriate tag for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is pretty general and kind of boils down to preference, but you could use a `fieldset` tag to group the fields, and then use a `legend` tag for the header.

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Favorite Foods</legend>
    <label for="food1">Rice</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="food1" name="food"><br>
    <label for="food2">Pasta</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="food2" name="food"><br>
    <label for="food3">Meat</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="food3" name="food"><br><br>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What if they were already inside a fieldset? Is a fieldset inside a fieldset semantically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is semantically correct to nest them: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element  There's an example of nesting at the bottom.